# Error launching "pepper_bringup pepper_full.launch"

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello !
Thank you for viewing this question.
I have recently tried to launch pepper_bringup pepper_full.launch on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I use ROS kinetic.
But I couldn't connect to pepper. In this August, I could connect to pepper that command.
When I tried it in this November , it was failed !

I was following this site from http://wiki.ros.org/pepper_bringup

Please help me !!

```
$ roslaunch pepper_bringup pepper_full.launch nao_ip:=192.168.11.24 network_interface:=wlp2s0



SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /pepper_robot/pose/pose_manager/poses/init/joint_names: ['Body']
 * /pepper_robot/pose/pose_manager/poses/init/positions: [0.0, 0.0, 1.39, ...
 * /pepper_robot/pose/pose_manager/poses/init/time_from_start: 1.5
 * /pepper_robot/pose/pose_manager/poses/zero/joint_names: ['Body']
 * /pepper_robot/pose/pose_manager/poses/zero/positions: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0...
 * /pepper_robot/pose/pose_manager/poses/zero/time_from_start: 1.5
 * /pepper_robot/pose/pose_manager/xap: /opt/ros/kinetic/...
 * /rosdistro: kinetic
 * /rosversion: 1.12.6

NODES
  /pepper_robot/pose/
    pose_controller (naoqi_pose/pose_controller.py)
    pose_manager (naoqi_pose/pose_manager.py)
  /pepper_robot/
    naoqi_driver (naoqi_driver/naoqi_driver_node)

ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

core service [/rosout] found
process[pepper_robot/naoqi_driver-1]: started with pid [2735]
process[pepper_robot/pose/pose_controller-2]: started with pid [2736]
process[pepper_robot/pose/pose_manager-3]: started with pid [2737]
Receiving information about robot model
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/naoqi_pose/pose_controller.py", line 49, in <module>
    from naoqi_driver.naoqi_node import NaoqiNode
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/naoqi_driver/__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
    from .naoqi_node import *
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/naoqi_driver/naoqi_node.py", line 37, in <module>
    raise RuntimeError("Error importing NaoQI. Please make sure that Aldebaran's NaoQI API is in your PYTHONPATH.")
RuntimeError: Error importing NaoQI. Please make sure that Aldebaran's NaoQI API is in your PYTHONPATH.
set prefix successfully to 
[I] 1481279744.207391 2735 qimessaging.session: Session listener created on tcp://0.0.0.0:0
[I] 1481279744.208074 2735 qimessaging.transportserver: TransportServer will listen on: tcp://127.0.0.1:38764
[I] 1481279744.208117 2735 qimessaging.transportserver: TransportServer will listen on: tcp://192.168.11.39:38764
using ip address: 127.0.0.1 @ wlp2s0
[pepper_robot/pose/pose_controller-2] process has died [pid 2736, exit code 1, cmd /opt/ros/kinetic/lib/naoqi_pose/pose_controller.py --pip=192.168.11.24 --pport=9559 __name:=pose_controller __log:=/home/cm9/.ros/log/b85df216-bdf9-11e6-a10b-5ce0c51af77f/pepper_robot-pose-pose_controller-2.log].
log file: /home/cm9/.ros/log/b85df216-bdf9-11e6-a10b-5ce0c51af77f/pepper_robot-pose-pose_controller-2*.log
found a catkin prefix /opt/ros/kinetic/share/naoqi_driver/share/boot_config.json
load boot config from /opt/ros/kinetic/share/naoqi_driver/share/boot_config.json
no camera information found for camera_source 3 and res: 1
found a catkin URDF /opt/ros/kinetic/share/naoqi_driver/share/urdf/pepper.urdf
Audio Extractor: Start
RightBumperPressed
LeftBumperPressed
BackBumperPressed
ROS-Driver-RightBumperPressed : Start
HandRightBackTouched
HandRightLeftTouched
HandRightRightTouched
HandLeftBackTouched
HandLeftLeftTouched
HandLeftRightTouched
ROS-Driver-HandRightBackTouched : Start
FrontTactilTouched
MiddleTactilTouched
RearTactilTouched
ROS-Driver-FrontTactilTouched : Start
registered subscriber:  teleop
registered subscriber:  moveto
registered subscriber:  speech
nodehandle reset 
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'ros::InvalidNameException'
  what():  The node name must not be empty
================================================================================REQUIRED process [pepper_robot/naoqi_driver-1] has died!
process has died [pid 2735, exit code -6, cmd /opt/ros/kinetic/lib/naoqi_driver/naoqi_driver_node --qi-url=tcp://192.168.11.24:9559 --roscore_ip=127.0.0.1 --network_interface=wlp2s0 __name:=naoqi_driver __log:=/home/cm9/.ros/log/b85df216-bdf9-11e6-a10b-5ce0c51af77f/pepper_robot-naoqi_driver-1.log].
log file: /home/cm9/.ros/log/b85df216-bdf9-11e6-a10b-5ce0c51af77f/pepper_robot-naoqi_driver-1*.log
Initiating shutdown!
================================================================================
[pepper_robot/pose/pose_manager-3] killing on exit
[pepper_robot/naoqi_driver-1] killing on exit
[FATAL] [1481279745.810786]: Could not connect to required "joint_trajectory" action server, is the nao_controller node running?
shutting down processing monitor...
... shutting down processing monitor complete
done
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/249732/error-launching-%22pepper_bringup-pepper_full.launch%22/) by [Sasamori](https://answers.ros.org/users/28763/sasamori/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2016-12-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-12-09**:
Please use the *Preformatted Text* button (the one with `101010` on it) to properly format console copy/pastes, launch files and code. That makes things much easier to read. Just select the text and press the button (or `ctrl+k`).

Thanks.

**Comment by [Sasamori](https://answers.ros.org/users/28763/sasamori/) on 2016-12-09**:
Thank you for your comments.
I changed text format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I try "roslaunch pepper_bringup pepper_full_py.launch ... "    I succeed in connecting to pepper !
But I cannot "roslaunch pepper_bringup pepper_full.launch..." .

I edit "pepper_full.launch" file after.

```
<launch>

  <arg name="nao_ip"              default="$(optenv NAO_IP)" />
  <arg name="nao_port"            default="$(optenv NAO_PORT 9559)" />

  <arg name="roscore_ip"          default="127.0.0.1" />
  <arg name="network_interface"   default="eth0" />

  <arg name="namespace"           default="pepper_robot" />

  <!-- naoqi driver -->
  <include file="$(find naoqi_driver)/launch/naoqi_driver.launch"  >
    <arg name="nao_ip"            value="$(arg nao_ip)" />
    <arg name="nao_port"          value="$(arg nao_port)" />
    <arg name="roscore_ip"        value="$(arg roscore_ip)" />
    <arg name="network_interface" value="$(arg network_interface)" />
  </include>

  <!-- launch pose manager -->
  <include file="$(find naoqi_pose)/launch/pose_manager.launch" ns="$(arg namespace)/pose" >
    <arg name="nao_ip"            value="$(arg nao_ip)" />
    <arg name="nao_port"          value="$(arg nao_port)" />
  </include>

  <!-- launch perception -->
  <include file="$(find pepper_bringup)/launch/perception.launch.xml">
    <arg name="namespace"         value="$(arg namespace)" />
  </include>

</launch>
```

I can launch "pepper_full.launch" !

---

Originally posted by [Sasamori](https://answers.ros.org/users/28763/sasamori/) with karma: 16 on 2016-12-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0